# Combine all content from several files, find matching strings and get a count of each line

Tags: powershell, text, powershell-2.0

I know how to get the data and search through it using some pattern.  But that is not what I need.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml | Get-Content | Select-String -pattern "something here"
```

I am searching through 100's of GPO xml files and we are trying to remove GPO's that perform the same thing over and over again.  I want to find the unique values and combine them in one big happy gpo and get rid of all the redundant ones.

My goal :

1)  Get all information from all *.xml files from 100's of sub folders and combine them into one file.

2)  Find all lines that contain the same string and get a count of that string.  I need a count for all strings in the combined file.

3)  My goal is to find the lines that are unique and save them to a file, for further use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty approach using a `Hashtable`.  Since the `Hashtable` setter performs an "update or create", you'll end up with a distinct list:

```powershell
$ht = @{}
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml | Get-Content | %{$ht[$_] = $true}
$ht.Keys
```

Edit: Just saw you wanted counts as well.  You can do this:

```powershell
$ht = @{}
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml | Get-Content | %{$ht[$_] = $ht[$_]+1}
$ht
```

To export to CSV:

```powershell
$ht.GetEnumerator() | select key, value | Export-Csv D:\output.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Jon!  Now can you show me hot to export this into a csv file please?

Comment: No problem.  Added csv output to my answer.